# WordPress vs. Custom PHP

Tags: php, cms

My client has NGO website built in custom PHP, he approached me for its revamp. I told him to build it in WordPress. But he has following concerns; and asked me WordPress vs. Custom PHP comparison.

1. Which is more secure, WordPress websites are more venerable to hacking etc.
2. Which one is more SEO friendly
3. Any other advantage of WordPress over custom PHP

Comment: This question will most probably be closed as primarily opinion based. Any programming languages will have some security issues. You will never be able to build a completely save website, a pro hacker will always find a loophole somewhere no matter what. As for your questions, it all comes down to your site, usability and understanding of the program involved. As for SEO, the programming language does not matter, what matter is your content and how you optimize the site and content for SEO purposes

Comment: you can't compare between known and unknown. In my experience costume php sites of this nature (i.e. not something that used by a big portal) stink all the way to hell, but this is just anecdotal.

Answer (score 2):

1) That depends on who is building the custom PHP site and how much effort they put into it. If you build a shoddy custom PHP site, then it can easily be hacked. On the other hand, if you don't take certain precautions then your WP site can be hacked too. I just finished up a site for a U.S. Congressman, and their IT guys tried to hack it but couldn't so they approved it for usage. If WP can be secure enough for the US Govt, it should be fine for your NGO.

2) No framework or CMS is "more SEO friendly". Some are EASIER to setup than others, but at the end of the day it's up to the developer to make sure you have proper h1, h2, etc tags. Meta tags, alt tags, unique content, etc etc. WordPress has tons of plugins that make your job A LOT easier in that regard.

3) Way easier to edit content, post new content, etc than a custom built php site. Development time is drastically reduced because everything is built for you.